# IE11/Edge solution for ...rest (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have the following code, which is working perfectly in Chrome/FF, but in IE/Edge I am getting an error.

```
var infoOut = infoIn.map(function (_ref) {
var Details = _ref.Details,
rest = _objectWithoutProperties(_ref, ["Details"]);

return { ...rest,
DetailsFrom: Details.split(" or ")
};
});
console.log(infoOut);
```

Because I am still learning Javascript, I have had to rely on Babel in the past to help with compatibility issues for IE. Unfortunately this time I am not so lucky.

This is the error I am getting when checking IE/Edge browser.

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
```

Which is in relation to this section of the code:

```
return { ...rest,
DetailsFrom: Details.split(" and ")
};
```

Suggestions would be great in helping to resolve this issue.
Thank you.